# pass formGroup in child component (Angular 5)

Tags: angular, angular5

I want to make a child component that takes the formGroup and adds validations but I receive an error because the child component does not perceive that it is inside the parent's "form"

How could I solve this problem?

father component:

```
<form [formGroup]="formulario">
    <app-campo [(propiedad)]="usuario.correo"
                               placeholder="title"
                               email="true"
                               [(formulario)]="formulario"
                    ></app-campo>
  </form>
```

child component:

```
<h3>Label</h3>
    <input
           placeholder="{{placeholder}}"
           [(ngModel)]="valorPropiedad"
           name="campo"
           (ngModelChange)="cambiar($event)"
           formControlName="campo"
           type="{{tipoInput}}">
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/iyvemjyYAq6hY4jzHihu?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution:

> Connecting parent component 'formGroup' with child component
>   'formControlName'
>
> In the Parent component template
>
> ```
> <form [formGroup]="recipeForm">
> <app-recipe-name [parent]="recipeForm"></app-recipe-name>
> </form>
> ```
>
> In the Child component, under the class add
>
> ```
> @Input() parent: FormGroup;
> ```
>
> In the Child component template
>
> ```
> <mat-input-container fxFill [formGroup]="parent">
>    <input matInput placeholder="Recipe Name" [matAutocomplete]="recipeAutocomplete" formControlName="recipeName">
> </mat-input-container>
> ```
>
> Now 'recipeName' is accessible from parent

By: https://gist.github.com/canabady/3e4b96717057411510f2dc8c7ddfdaf7

Answer (score 1):

in the child component you cannot specify the `formControlName` without specifying the `formGroup`, so what you have to do is to add the formGroup in your child component :

**Child Component Code :**

```
<div [formGroup]="formulario">
      <h3>Label</h3>
      <input
           placeholder="{{placeholder}}"
           [(ngModel)]="valorPropiedad"
           name="campo"
           (ngModelChange)="cambiar($event)"
           formControlName="campo"
           type="{{tipoInput}}">
</div>
```

Regards ,